# Does recording to a text document in php work the same for linux as it does in windows

Tags: php, html, linux, windows

I have recently been figuring out how to use php and have found how to record a input through a form on a standard .txt file however when transferring this from my windows computer (running wamp server) to Linux (which is running Kali Linux) the text file is blank and which I am assuming means that there has been nothing recorded. Yes I have apache running on the Linux system however when on localhost it does not work unlike on my windows. My guess is that it may have to do with the fact that Linux and Windows could interact differently with text files but I am unsure. Thank you for any help code is below for the practice website.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

        <style>
            @font-fact{
                font-family: Penguin; src: url("Penguin Sans 0.500.ttf");
            }
            body{

                font-family: Penguin, monospace;

                }
            html{
                height: 100%;
                margin:0px;
                background: url("background.png") no-repeat center center;
                background-size: cover;
                background-attachment: fixed;
            }
            .headimage{
                margin-left: -3%;
                margin-top: .5%;
            }
            .survey{
                margin-top: 5%;
                padding-bottom: 5%;

            }
            a{
                text-decoration: none;
                color: white;
            }
            .button {
                background-color: green;
                border: none;
                color: purple;
                padding: 5px;
                text-align: center;
                text-decoration: none;
                display: inline-block;
                font-size: 16px;
                margin: 4px 2px;
                cursor: pointer;
            }
            .buttonpay{
                border-radius: 12px;
            }

            .buttonpay:hover{
                color: green;
                background-color: purple;
            }
            .buycodebox{
                background-color: white;
                color: red;
                border: none;
                padding: 10px;
                text-align: center;
                text-decoration: none;
                display: inline-block;
                font-size: 20px;
                margin: 10px;
                font-family: monospace;
            }
            .too{
                border-width: 1px;
                background-color: #afd99c; 
                border-radius: 4px;
                border-color: purple;
              }
              form{
                width: 25%;
              }
              .to{
                background-color: purple;
                color: green;
                border-radius: 4px;
                border-color: purple;
              }
              .to:hover{
                background-color:green;
                color: purple;
                border-color: green;
              }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class = "headimage"><img src="THISISTHEONEgreen.png"  width="15%"></div>
        <!--BUY CODE-->
        <center>
        <div class = "buycodebox">
            CODE = BLUEFADESMALL
        </div>
        <center>
            <form method="post">
            CODE<br>
            <input type="text" name="textdata" class = "too"><br>
            ADDRESS<br>
            <input type="text" name="textdata1" class = "too"><br>
            STATE<br>
            <input type="text" name="textdata2" class = "too"><br>
            CITY<br>
            <input type="text" name="textdata3" class = "too"><br>
            ZIP<br>
            <input type="text" name="textdata4" class = "too"><br>
            <br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT" class ="to">
          </form>
        </center>
        <br>
        ONCE FILLED OUT
        <br>
        <br>
        <center>
            <a href = "#"><button class="button buttonpay">CONTINUE</button></a>
        </center>
        <center>
        <p>
            QUESTIONS?
        </p>
        </center>




    </body>
</html>
<?php

 if(isset($_POST['textdata']))
 if(isset($_POST['textdata1']))
 if(isset($_POST['textdata2']))
 if(isset($_POST['textdata3'])) 
 if(isset($_POST['textdata4']))
 {
 $data=$_POST['textdata'];
 $data1=$_POST['textdata1'];
 $data2=$_POST['textdata2'];
 $data3=$_POST['textdata3'];
 $data4=$_POST['textdata4'];
 $fp = fopen('data.txt', 'a');

 fwrite($fp, $data . ",");
 fwrite($fp, $data1 . ",");
 fwrite($fp, $data2 . ",");
 fwrite($fp, $data3 . ",");
 fwrite($fp, $data4 . "/" );
 fclose($fp);
 }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a permissions issue.

Try to run this command:

```
chmod 777 data.txt
```